# Toggle Color based on RGB or Hex values of DOM element

Tags: javascript, css, colors

Why does the following code not toggle the element color when the button is clicked? My assumption is that the `style.color` is returning an object of sorts and not a string. What would be the best way to correct this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
asd=document.getElementById("demo")
if (asd.style.color!="rgb(255,0,0)")
asd.style.color="rgb(255,0,0)";
else
asd.style.color="rgb(0,0,0)";
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<p id="demo">
JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.
</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser vendors return various *versions* of the `style.color` value.

From a quick test on this very page (which by pasting the code into the JavaScript console you can see for yourself):

- IE8 returns `"#888"` for `document.querySelectorAll('div[class="user-details"]')[0].currentStyle.color`
- Chrome and Firefox return `"rgb(136, 136, 136)"` for `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('user-details')[0], null)['color']`

I'm fairly sure I've seen a previous version of one browser return `"rgb(136,136,136)"` (without spaces) before.

One way to work around this inconsistency is to define the colors in CSS classes instead and toggle between the class names.

A *very* [**simple demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/N2PTH/) of this would be the following code. However this is *very* simple as it would only work if the element has a single CSS class. You would need to write a utility function to check if an element has a class applied and functions to add and remove a single class from a list if your design needed multiple classes. These have been written many times before so there are plenty of examples (search for `javascript hasclass addclass removeclass`) or use an existing utility library.

**CSS**

```
.on {
    color:#f00;
}

.off {
    color:#000;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction() {
    var e = document.getElementById("demo");

    e.className = e.className === 'on' ? e.className = 'off' : e.className = 'on';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<p id="demo" class="off">
JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.
</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, thanks for the explanation and added clarification.

Comment: Happy to help. I just added a small demo to the answer, although it has a few caveats you might want to consider.

Answer (score 0):

The browser sets an inline rgb color with spaces after the commas, so your *if* statement has to match the string exactly. Adding spaces after your commas in your rgb value will make this work.

```
if (asd.style.color!="rgb(255, 0, 0)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById("color1").style.color!="#FF0000")
{
document.getElementById("color1").style.color="#FF0000";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("color1").style.color="#FFFFFF";
}
```

Try this hope will work.